# React - props is not a function

Tags: reactjs

Yet another one of these questions. I know there are several here, but I can't see my mistake.

My code is based on "create-react-app" via Visual Studio 2019, so the boilerplate should look familiar.

I'm passing a *function* called "**updateTodoCheckbox**" from the parent **FetchData** component to my **TodoItem** component via a *property* called "**onCheckboxUpdate**.

When *handleInputChange* is called via the *onChange* for the checkbox (which has the name property *isComplete*), I get:

> TypeError: this.props.onCheckboxUpdate is not a function

I have called bind on the function in the constructor. I've also tried passing it as an arrow function. Same result, so I don't think it's a binding issue.

Any help appreciated to see my error. I'm sure it's a simple one.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class TodoItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isComplete: props.data.isComplete
    }

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this); // otherwise this.setState will be undefined

  }

    handleInputChange(inputEvent) {

      const target = inputEvent.target;
      const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
      const name = target.name;

      if (name == "isComplete")
      {
        this.props.onCheckboxUpdate(); // This fails        
      }

      this.setState({
       [name]: value 
      });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="form-group" key={this.props.data.id}>
          <div className="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="isComplete" checked={this.state.isComplete} id={this.props.data.id} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
            <label class="form-check-label" for={this.props.data.id}>{this.props.data.name} - {this.props.data.categoryId}</label>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export class FetchData extends Component {
  static displayName = FetchData.name;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { todoData: [], loading: true };

    this.updateTodoCheckbox = this.updateTodoCheckbox.bind(this);

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.populateTodoData();
  }

  static renderTodoData(todoData) {
      return (
        <form>
            {todoData.map(todo =>
                <TodoItem data={todo}
                  onCheckboxUpdate={this.updateTodoCheckbox} />
            )}
        </form>        
    );
  }

  render() {
    let contents = this.state.loading
      ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
      : FetchData.renderTodoData(this.state.todoData);

    return (
      <div>
        <h1 id="tabelLabel" >TODO</h1>
        <p>A list of things to do</p>
        {contents}
      </div>
    );
  }

  async populateTodoData() {
    const response = await fetch('api/TodoItems');
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ todoData: data, loading: false });
  }

  async updateTodoCheckbox() {
    
    console.log(test);
    // some await call will go here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems looks to be the `renderTodoData(todoData)` render function as it is marked as `static`. Functions that have been marked as static do not have access to class scope variables/functions as they. Code placed in static scope can only acres other variables/functions that is also static (other static functions for example).

You should be ae to remove the `static` keyword from `renderTodoData(todoData)`. You may need to bind it as you did with `handleInputChange` in your constructor.

Comment: Thanks! You got it. I didn't need to bind it, but I did need to update the render method from FetchData.renderTodoData to this.renderTodoData

Answer (score 2):

Problem is `static renderTodoData(todoData)` function which is static and which, because of that, doesn't know about "this" (it can only access to the other static methods). Try not having that function as static.